# Details of program/script which runs when we download a file in windows

Tags: windows-8, download, csrss

Where can I find details of program/script which runs when we download any file in windows. When I click on a download link it automatically starts downloading. Which script is responsible for download on windows ? is it Client server runtime Process?

Comment: Your question is too vague. There are many ways for an app to perform a download. The most common way is for the app to perform the download itself manually. There are system services for background downloads (e.g. [BackgroundDownloader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounddownloader.aspx) class and [BITS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362708(v=vs.85).aspx)) but they are not commonly used by Web browsers, which is what I think you're asking about when you say "a download link".